# How to draw list view behind status bar without padding?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here's what I want to achieve:

[image: The scaffold content is behind the status bar]

This is what I have now:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            'assets/images/videosbg.png',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            height: 300,
            width: double.infinity,
          ),
          ...
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: The scaffold content is below the status bar]

I don't want to remove the status bar or change its color, so SystemChrome didn't work for me.

How to place scaffold body behind status bar, not below? Do I need to somehow remove the upper padding of the status bar?

Comment: I've tried setting the color to transparent in main() as some answers below suggest, but nothing has changed. The upper padding is still there. Maybe my widget structure is wrong or I should change something in Scaffold?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ListView has padding property, set this to `EdgeInsets.zero`

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            'assets/images/videosbg.png',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            height: 300,
            width: double.infinity,
          ),
          ...
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

FYI https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14842

Answer (score 1):

I tried to put the SystemChrome with transparent color in the main() function before running the MaterialApp

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
  SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent),
);
```

and I was able to reproduce what you're looking for
[image]

Comment: I've tried setting the color to transparent in main(), but nothing has changed. The upper padding is still there. Maybe my widget structure is wrong or I should change something in Scaffold?

Answer (score 1):

**For Android YES**

`SystemChrome` is used for setting the bar transparent. That class provides a `setSystemUIOverlayStyle` method and you can use it like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main(){
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  ));
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: @Darkhan: Could you let me know whether this solution worked for you or not

Comment: I've tried setting the color to transparent in main(), but nothing has changed. It seems that the issue is not with color but with the padding. Maybe my widget structure is wrong or I should change something in Scaffold?

Comment: The scaffold is for your screen, it will not going to help you.